# I get a Python error returns 'GeoDataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, heatmap, geopandas

I am trying to create and export a Heatmap to a png.
I imported a Shapefile, read the fields into a geodataframe.
I can print out the geodataframe in head().

I get an error that the 'GeoDataFrame' object is not callable?
I have tried several changes, but not getting anywhere, and would appreciate assistance to resolve this.

'''

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame as gdf
from shapely.geometry import Point
#import gmaps
#import gmaps.datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#### Set the filepath and load in a shapefile
fp = r'C:\Temp\PROJECTS\CCRT\ClimateChangeFME\Modelling\Shp\Lightning_2000_PT.shp'
map_df = gpd.read_file(fp)

#### Check data type not a normal dataframe, but a GEOdataframe
#print(map_df.head())

#### Preview map
#map_df.plot()

#data_for_map = map_df.rename(index=str, columns={"grid_id": "grid_id",  "climate_sc": "climate_scenario", "climate_ha": "climate_hazard",  "hazard_lev": "hazard_level", "hazard_l_1": "hazard_level_order", "hazard_ind": "hazard_indicator"})

data_for_map = map_df(index=str, columns={"grid_id": "grid_id",  "hazard_ind": "hazard_ind"})
#print(data_for_map.head())

### Set a variable that will call whatever column we want to visualise on the map
variable = 'hazard_ind'

### Set the range for the chloropleth
vmin, vmax = 50, 82

### Create figure and axes for Matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(50, 20))

### Create map
map_df.plot(column=variable, cmap='Blues', linewidth=0.8, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8')

### Remove the axis
ax.axis('off')

### Add a title
#ax.set_title('Preventable death rate in London', fontdict={'fontsize': '25', 'fontweight' : '3'})

### Create colorbar as a legend
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='Blues', norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))

# Empty array for the data range
sm._A = []

# Add the colorbar to the figure
#cbar = fig.colorbar(sm)

# Save the figure
fig.savefig("Lightning_2000.png", dpi=600)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

> I get an error that the 'GeoDataFrame' object is not callable?

It would be best to post the full error, but from this and the code I am quite certain this is one problem

```py
data_for_map = map_df(index=str, columns={"grid_id": "grid_id",  "hazard_ind": "hazard_ind"})
```

The `map_df` is a `GeoDataFrame` and it is not callable like a function, it does not implement the `__call__` function. See here what it all supports https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/geodataframe.html

I supposed you meant to run some other function from it. I sadly have no idea about the library and what you generally want to achieve, so can't help you with what to use. It is best to check documentation and maybe some examples, the documentation seems quite good.